# How to force the Commit log's commit to memtable?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0

I'm using the sstableloader's command to load the backup and I note that the new datas not load. Analising the files, the new datas still in the commit log and not in the backup. How could I force the "commit" the commit log datas in the memtables?

Comment: Do you mean that the backup used has commits in the commitlog that were not in the sstables - and you are trying to get the commit log to replay on the node after the restore?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do that. It is to  have  the same data at the two dbs. Is it not correct to do? Do you understand what I am trying to do? Depending the time that backup run, the data is not synchronized.

Comment: The sstableloader's command not show errors, but when I select the new data it is not at the table as if not loaded.

Comment: On the 2nd node being restore to - did system files get restored? I suspect the new nodes host_id is different, so the commit logs would not replay, even if in place.

Comment: @Andrew, they have the same strurcture. I did the secound step the anwser below and I saw the date's file update (it was not happenning before). I'm waiting the load to finish. I'll tell you the result.

Comment: @Andrew, it's running well the script to load the bkp. The command nodetool drain resolved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So normally, I'd say try running a `nodetool flush`.  If data is getting flushed from memory to disk, it should remove the corresponding commitlog file.

If that's not happening, the next thing I would try is stopping the node with `nodetool drain` and then stopping the Cassandra process.  When you restart it, the node will process the commitlogs and reconcile them with data stored on disk.

Comment: Hi, Aaron, the sstable's file date was update (it was not happenning) . I used the secound step the answer. However after the load, the log show that the table doesn't exist. But the structure is the same in the two nodes. We are using this line to load: `find . -maxdepth 5 -type d -exec sstableloader -v --nodes 127.0.0.1 {} \;` . Do we are doing something wrong? We are replication the date between to cassandras's db (same structure).

Comment: We ran the command line again and it was ok! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @LucianaOliveira excellent, I’m glad it worked!